# How to perform a distribution fit test to censored data

Tags: fitting, distributions

With following code I will get an error:

```
data = Flatten[{595, 1431, 4347, 5554, 6279, 6887, Table[{7100, \[Infinity]}, {10}]}, 1];
e = EventData[data];
DistributionFitTest[e, WeibullDistribution[a, b]]
```

a and b are the unknown parameter of the Weibull distribution.

Providing with estimated parameter will not help (again the same error message):

```
d = EstimatedDistribution[e, WeibullDistribution[a, b], ParameterEstimator -> {"MaximumLikelihood", Method -> "NMaximize"}]
DistributionFitTest[data, d]
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Mathematica.SE, please consider taking the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) so you learn the basics of the site. Once you gain enough reputation by making [good questions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) you will be able to vote up and down both questions and answers. When you see good ones, please vote them up by clicking the grey triangles, because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. As you receive help, try to give it too, by *answering questions* in your area of expertise.

Comment: Can you please explain the format of your data? Clearly that is not accepted by [`EventData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EventData.html). The solution probably goes in the lines of `FindDistributionParameters[cdata, CensoredDistribution[{leftCensor, rightCensor}, WeibullDistribution[a, b]]`

Comment: Does `DistrubutionFitTest` accept *data* with `Head == EventData`?

Comment: To my knowledge `DistributionFitTest` does not work with `EventData`.

Answer (score 1):

@rhermans gave you the answer in a comment.

```
data = Flatten[{595, 1431, 4347, 5554, 6279, 6887, Table[7100, {10}]},
    1];

wcd = CensoredDistribution[{leftCensor, rightCensor}, WeibullDistribution[a, b]];
FindDistributionParameters[data, wcd]
(* {leftCensor -> 595.,rightCensor -> 7100.,a -> 1.1017281600526971,b -> 14712.282885780418} *)
DistributionFitTest[data, wcd, "PearsonChiSquare"]
(* 0.05125258285736953 *)
```

If `leftCensor` is known to be zero, then you could use

```
wcd = CensoredDistribution[{0, rightCensor}, WeibullDistribution[a, b]];
FindDistributionParameters[data, wcd]
(* {rightCensor -> 7100.,a -> 1.3102715493177497,b -> 12977.89931682844} *)
DistributionFitTest[data, wcd, "PearsonChiSquare"]
(* 0.17573433564422514 *)
```

While for this particular distribution `DistributionFitTest` chooses `PearsonChiSquare`, one should make this explicit or at least determine which test was used.  If you choose some of the other tests, you'll likely see a warning that the *P*-value is bogus due to the fact that you've had to estimate some of the parameters.

And, finally, if you only have 7 unique values, the best you can do when the *P*-value is large is to say "Well, maybe there aren't any gross departures observed."